# Get CSRF token in Listner symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a senario where I have to get a a CSRF token from a request listner in symfony3. The thing is I dont know how. I know in the controller one does this.

```
   $_token = $this->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('form')
```

My question is how would you get it from the listner withlut using $this

Answer (score 0):

[You can add the token provider as argument to your Listener's constructor](https://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services). [In your service definition you pass the token provider as argument](https://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container). You can refer to it by it's service id `form.csrf_provider`. Then you can use the provider just as you would in your controller.

Comment: Do your own work please. Expand your question if you get stuck.